# I am no longer able to boot through windows or ubuntu. Do I need to replace my hard drive?

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, windows-10

I have been using an Asus Laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 dual booted.
A few days ago while I was using ubuntu, a black screen suddenly appeared
[The black screen that appeared while I was using ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP0WH.png)

After that, I haven't been able to boot ubuntu or windows. Windows says some essential driver/something is missing and I need a recovery disk/something.
When I try to boot ubuntu, this happens:
[The error that appears whenever I try to boot ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN11E.jpg)

Running an fsck through recovery mode didn't solve the problem.

I have been able to backup my data by booting through a pendrive. But when I tried copying stuff from my laptop the pendrive, I wasn't able to copy all of it. There were input/output errors for a lot of files.

When I tried to install ubuntu using the same pendrive, the whole thing got stuck.

How do I solve this situation? Do I need to buy a new hard drive or not?

Comment: I think it's disk problem!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I think so too. The question I have is, can it be solved without replacing the disk?

Comment: Looks like your HDD crashed. Problems with HDD sectors as you can see in the image happens repeatedly. You can try to reinstall a fresh copy of any OS. Depending on the number of sectors affected in the crash it might be usable or completely useless

Comment: Try this. Boot using live Ubuntu and try to mount the HDD. If it mounts it will be usable otherwise the only other choice is to replace HDD

Comment: Booting using live Ubuntu = Booting through a pen drive? And how do I mount the HDD?

Comment: My suggestion would be to ask your HDD for it's health condition (ie. read it's SMART or self-monitoring... data).  This reads from the circuitry and doesn't involve platters so if the disk is dying; you've aren't using any remaining health.  I'd suggest `smartctl` (full details, if you like terminal) or `gnome-disks` will show this (run from Ubuntu install media or 'live')  telling you the health of your drive as *facts* from your actual hardware.  You can then know instead of guessing...

Comment: @guiverc It says disk is OK, 16376 bad sectors
And this is the output of smartctl: https://pastebin.com/QXrgZkMz
What does all this mean?

Comment: Looking at the SMART data... your HDD has failed. Sorry.

Comment: Can I simply buy any internal hard drive and insert it?

Comment: Most 2.5" 5400 rpm hard drives, or SSD's, should work.